# How to handle arithmetic overflow errors while dealing with aggregating the long data in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Wondering if there is any way to handle arithmetic overflow while doing aggregation on the dataframes?  Note data is being aggregated over 30 day window and data is of `long` type.

Comment: Please provide an example what kind of aggregation and how are you doing it. Max `long` is a pretty large number (range is -2^63 to 2^63 – 1). You sure you need more?

Comment: Thanks. Here is the snippet which i suspect might end up in overflow as the underlying fields i am aggregating  over a time window of 30 days  is of long type  def getAggregateddata(input: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    input
      .groupBy("id", "Type")
      .agg(
        sum("totalBytesX")
        sum("totalBytesFromY")
        sum("totalBytesFromZ")
   
}   Basically looking for safesum  while aggregating like if the value exceeds the underlying datatype max range, ignore that value and proceed with rest instead of failure

Comment: Worldwide volume of data created in 2020 is currently estimated at 50 zettabytes (50^21, https://www.statista.com/statistics/871513/worldwide-data-created/) so your aggregates would probably be fine. But if you dont think its safe enough, maybe create a UDF `safesum()`  that does arithmetic in `BigInteger`?

Comment: Thanks much. I guess it would be some type of custom aggregator in scala  ?  any sample example is of great help if possible. like in c#, public class SafeSum : Aggregate<long, long>     {     long sum = 0;  bool isValid = true;public override void Initialize()
        {  sum = 0; isValid = true;}  public override void Add(long y)    {
            try
            { if (isValid)
                {    sum += y;    }   
               catch (Exception e)
            {   isValid = false;            }
        }      public override long Finalize() { return (isValid) ? sum : -1;

Comment: I guess any example for UserDefinedTypedAggregation for summing would be great

Comment: Don't have one myself, but maybe one of the Hive UDAF examples can be adapted? https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/udaf/example

Comment: Thanks much for the pointers